# java.util.NoSuchElementException found while using Scanner

Tags: java, exception, input, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am a new newbie and trying to learn and practice java code simultaneously. Its really basic but still i am stuck. While coming across Scanner class, i am facing below error. I am already through a lot many solutions provided earlier over here but still i am unable to resolve it

> ### Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Please find the code below:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.IOException;
    public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try
    {
        chk();
    }
    catch(final IOException x)
    {
        x.printStackTrace();
    } 
    
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void chk() throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value,i=0;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number :");
            while (!sc.hasNextInt()) 
            {
                sc.nextInt(); 
                
            }
            value = sc.nextInt();
            if (value > 0) {
                if (value > 20) {
                    System.out.println("Valuable customer");
                } else
                    System.out.println("Not a valuable customer");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");

        }
        sc.close();
    }
    }

**Error Message**

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Main.chk(Main.java:27)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)`
```

Comment: Please, format the code!

Comment: @rabbitguy the duplicate you've marked deals with reading from the scanner while also reading from the same reader. This isn't the issue here

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethink your logic. Here you are saying "While the scanner doesn't have a next int, try to get the next int"

```
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        sc.nextInt(); 

    }
```

Comment: Hi @controlaltdel . I am just trying to conform over here is that the console input is of integer type and if its yes, then i am assigning it to the variable `value`

Comment: I just remove the  ` ! sign from while (sc.hasNextInt())`  and the code is working now. Thanks for your guidence @controlaltdel